# XSLT convert dateTime with default timezone

Tags: datetime, xslt

I have a date in my input XML `01.08.2013 11:22` that needs to be converted into this format `2013-08-01T11:22:00+02:00`.

My Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<input>01.08.2013 11:22</input>
```

Desired ouput

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<output>2013-08-01T11:22:00+02:00</output>
```

What I did so far:

1. Convert `01.08.2013 11:22` to a xs:dateTime OK (with my own function)
2. Convert the standard xs:dateTime to `2013-08-01T11:22:00+02:00` Here I failed, because I don't have a timezone defined. I need to take the servers default timezone (may change when daylight saving time in summer)

First of all I searched for a standard operation but did not find anything. So I created my own string based function that convert the input to a standard date, this is working.

But now my output 2) is not working, because I don't have a timezone, my output is always this `2013-8-1T11:22:00` without the timezone....

**How can I add the timezone to the date so that my output is correctly?**

**Or in general, how can I convert `01.08.2013 11:22` to `2013-08-01T11:22:00+02:00`?**

```
<xsl:template name="convertDate">
    <xsl:param name="givenDate"/>
    <!-- a) Convert `01.08.2013 11:22` to a xs:dateTime  -->
    <xsl:variable name="dd" select="substring-before($givenDate, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mmRest" select="substring-after($givenDate, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mm" select="substring-before($mmRest, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="yyyyRest" select="substring-after($mmRest, '.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="yyyy" select="substring-before($yyyyRest, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="hhRest" select="substring-after($yyyyRest, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="hh" select="substring-before($hhRest, ':')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="min" select="substring-after($hhRest, ':')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="correctDate" select="xs:dateTime(concat($yyyy,'-',$mm,'-',$dd,'T',$hh,':',$min,':','00'))"/>        

    <!-- b) Convert the standard xs:dateTime to `2013-08-01T11:22:00+02:00`  -->
    <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($correctDate,'[Y]-[M]-[D]T[H]:[m]:[s][z]')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Since date time/time zones are hard (they really are), I would recommend strongly against using string functions for handling them. If you say what XSLT processor you are using, somebody can recommend a date/time-capable (extension) function that does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

What about`<xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>` which is an [XPATH 2.0 Function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-current-dateTime) and returns the timezone as well?

Comment: But I don't need the current dateTime, the dateTime is given in the input xml. Is there a calculation possible with the current-dateTime() to get my desired output? givenDateTime+current-dateTime()-current-DateTime() would again give the givenDateTime - but maybe with the timezone?

Comment: Just use the substring from the output:
2006-04-10T13:40:23.83-05:00
The last six characters are the time zone from the server where the xslt/xquery runs.